# Unregistering a BroadcastReceiver outside of a subscription when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, rx-java, rx-android

I've got this little util method that gets me an `Observable` to monitor Bluetooth state.

```
public static Observable<Integer> getBluetoothStateObservable(Context context) {
    final Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    return Observable.create(observer -> {
            final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    int btState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF);
                    switch (btState) {
                        case BluetoothAdapter.ERROR:
                            observer.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("Error occurred while changing bluetooth state"));
                            break;
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                            observer.onCompleted();
                            break;
                        default:
                            observer.onNext(btState);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            observer.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> appContext.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)));
            appContext.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
    })
}
```

When I use this method in my activity, I know when the user enabled the Bluetooth. This works fine, but it leaks when activity suddenly gets killed.

I can unsubscribe in `onDestroy`, but how can I unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`?

Any ideas?

Comment: The observable you have created doesn't support backpressure so to avoid triggering a `MissingBackpressureException` from a downstream operator you should combine it with `.onBackpressureXXX()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given how the getBluetoothStateObservable is setup, the BroadcastReceiver will be unregistered when the Subscriber unsubscribes. The only trick is to ensure that it does, in fact, get unsubscribed when the Android Activity lifecycle comes into play.

In this case, you can either retain a Subscription instance, or use a CompositeSubscription.

In onCreate or onStart (for example):

```
mSubscription = getBluetoothStateObservable(this).subscribe();
or 
mCompositeSubscription.add(getBluetoothStateObservable(this).subscribe());
```

in onDestroy or onStop:

```
mSubscription.unsubscribe();
or
mCompositeSubscription.clear();
```

As always, Dan Lew has great explanations of how Android Lifecycles should work with RxJava (http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't think that update an Activity that is in background (or killed) is a good practice (even if would be possible).

According to [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View). While activities are often presented to the user as full-screen windows, they can also be used in other ways: as floating windows... or embedded inside of another activity (using ActivityGroup).

So, if the Activity is in background, it does not visible. So, it is useless to update its contents (because it is not visible to user).

In fact, you should consider different approaches like:

- If you need to update a View in the activity, it makes sense to do it only when app is open. So, if the app was killed (or in Background), it is useless to update it (user is not seeing it anyway).
- If if you need to take a single action when a Bluetooth event happens, do it directly in `BroadcastReceiver`.
- If you need to run a long task, create a Service. This way, your `BroadcastReceiver` can start (and "talk" with) service after receiving the event that you are expecting.
- Use your BroadcastReceiver to store information for later use. This way, when user open your app again, you activity can consult the info that you saved and then, prepare the views accordingly (during `onCreate()` and `onResult()` method.

Remember:

- If you need to display a UI element, you need an Activity.
- If you need to be notified about events, you need a BroadcastReceiver.
- If you need to keep running some task in background, you need a Service.